# GetServerSideProps not getting called for nested page in Next with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a page set up at /article/[id] that is supposed to fetch an article for the id using getServerSideProps. It seems that getServerSideProps is not getting called at all since I don't see any of the console logs.

When I navigate to the page, it says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')" since article is undefined. When I replace the page content with simple static text, it shows up fine with the right url.

The file is currently called [id].tsx, but I tried different names with the same result.

```
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next'
import Link from 'next/link'

interface Article {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface ArticleProps {
  article: Article
}

const ArticleDetail: NextPage<ArticleProps> = ({ article }) => {
  return (
    // <p>Hello</p> // Shows up on the page
    <div>
      <h1>{article.title}</h1>
      <p>{article.body}</p>
      <br />
      <Link href="/">Go Back</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ArticleDetail

export const getServersideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  console.log("hello"); // this is never logged

  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${context.params?.id}`)
  const article = await res.json() as Article
  console.log(article); // this is never logged

  return {
    props: {
      article
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `getServerSideProps` (beware of the case sensitivity) to your page component in the /pages folder and then pass it down thru props. You can not use it in your nested React components

EDIT after your response: the issue is that your `getServerSideProps` never gets called because of your typo "`getServersideProps`"

Comment: It is a page at /pages/article/[id].tsx with ArticleDetail: NextPage. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: check editted comment

Comment: Whoops. Good catch. Thanks